# Python 3: Add two lists together at the same indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, join, merge

I am new to python and got the following issue which I try to solve:

I have two lists in Python 3 that I want to merge. The structure of the lists, is the following:

```
my_list_1 = [[0,1,0], [hello, hello, hello]]
my_list_2 = [[2,3,4], [bye,bye,bye]]

Output shall be: [[0,1,0,2,3,4], [hello, hello, hello, bye, bye, bye]]
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?
My idea is to compare the index of both lists and add them together, but sadly I don't know how.

best regards and thanks for any help!

Comment: Iterate over both and add the using `zip`: `[i+j for i,j in zip(my_list_1, my_list_2)]`

Comment: [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)